# Get the average color value from a region in an image

Tags: java, image, colors, clojure

## A working but very slow solution

Consider an `Image` object, which might be created like so:

```clj
(import 'javax.imageio.ImageIO)
(import 'java.awt.Color)
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(def img (ImageIO/read (io/file "/path/to/img.jpg")))
```

The following function extracts a sequence of pixels from a region of an `Image`. Each one is represented by a vector of RGB values:

```clj
(defn get-pixels [img [x y] [w h]] 
  (for [x (range x (+ x w))
        y (range y (+ y h))]
    (let [c (Color. (.getRGB img x y))]
      [(.getRed c) (.getGreen c) (.getBlue c)])))

(get-pixels img [0 0] [10 10])
;; ([254 252 240] [254 252 240] [254 252 240] [254 252 240] ...)
```

From this result, the average color can be calculated by this function:

```clj
(defn average-color [colors]
  (mapv #(/ % (count colors))
        (reduce (partial mapv +) colors)))
```

*(This would be more elegantly implemented with a vector library)*

However: This can be chained now like so, to get the intended result:

```clj
(average-color (get-pixels img [0 0] [10 10]))
;; [254 252 240]
```

The problem is that it is very slow, which is not quite surprising. I guess the bottleneck is inside the get-pixels function, which creates a `Color` object for each pixel.

## A more promising approach with wrong results

I was trying to work with this snippet:

```clj
(import 'java.awt.Rectangle)

(defn get-data [img [x y] [w h]] 
  (-> (.getData img (Rectangle. x y w h)) 
      .getDataBuffer 
      .getData))
```

With the same image:

```clj
(get-data img [0 0] [10 10])
;; #object["[B" 0x502f5b2a "[B@502f5b2a"]
(vec *1)
;; [-1 -16 -4 -2 -1 -16 -4 -2 -1 -16 -4 -2 -1 -16 ...]
```

I was not able to figure out how to further process this output for my purpose.

Does anybody know, how to improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are slightly wrong about the main bottleneck of your solution. First of all, your `get-pixels` uses reflection for `getRGB` method. Could be easily seen if you set `*warn-on-reflection*`

```
user> (set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
true

user> 
(defn get-pixels [img [x y] [w h]] 
  (for [x (range x (+ x w))
        y (range y (+ y h))]
    (let [c (Color. (.getRGB img x y))]
      [(.getRed c) (.getGreen c) (.getBlue c)])))

;;Reflection warning, *cider-repl localhost*:2136:21 - call to method getRGB can't be resolved (target class is unknown).
;;Reflection warning, *cider-repl localhost*:2136:21 - call to method getRGB can't be resolved (target class is unknown).
#'user/get-pixels

user> (time (average-color (get-pixels image [0 0] [300 300])))
;;"Elapsed time: 505.637246 msecs"
[4822271/22500 3535699/18000 15749839/90000]
```

so adding typehint should make it faster:

```
user> 
(defn get-pixels [^java.awt.image.BufferedImage img [x y] [w h]] 
  (for [x (range x (+ x w))
        y (range y (+ y h))]
    (let [c (Color. (.getRGB img x y))]
      [(.getRed c) (.getGreen c) (.getBlue c)])))
#'user/get-pixels

user> (time (average-color (get-pixels image [0 0] [300 300])))
;;"Elapsed time: 149.073099 msecs"
[4822271/22500 3535699/18000 15749839/90000]
```

now you can make some further optimizations. First of all i would start with replacing `mapv` in `average-color` reduction with simple component-wise addition:

```
user> 
(defn average-color [colors]
  (mapv #(/ % (count colors))
        (reduce (fn [[r g b] [r1 g1 b1]]
                  [(+ r r1) (+ g g1) (+ b b1)])
                colors)))
#'user/average-color

user> (time (average-color (get-pixels image [0 0] [300 300])))
"Elapsed time: 42.657254 msecs"
[4822271/22500 3535699/18000 15749839/90000]
```

ok. Now it's 10+ times faster then your first variant. But you can still oprimize it further. I would go with replacing `.getRGB` for every point with its overload for a rectangle, returning array of ints, and then just reduce it with `areduce`:

```
user> 
(defn get-pixels2 ^ints [^java.awt.image.BufferedImage img [x y] [w h]]
  (.getRGB img x y w h (int-array (* w h)) 0 w))
#'user/get-pixels2

user> 
(defn average-color2 [^ints pixels]
  (mapv #(/ % (count pixels))
        (areduce pixels idx ret [0 0 0]
                 (let [[r g b] ret
                       c (Color. (aget pixels idx))]
                   [(+ r (.getRed c))
                    (+ g (.getGreen c))
                    (+ b (.getBlue c))]))))
#'user/average-color2

user> (time (average-color2 (get-pixels2 image [0 0] [300 300])))
"Elapsed time: 14.601505 msecs"
[4822271/22500 3535699/18000 15749839/90000]
```

now i guess it should be acceptable. Also, you can try just using bitwise operations to get color components, instead of creating `Color` object, it could make it even faster, but personally i don't think it is needed.